# Iterating Though NSDictionary that has JSON Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

So I've got an `NSDictionary` that holds JSON data from doing the following:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&someError];
```

And when I NSLog my dictionary, I get the output below.

```
2015-06-11 17:13:49.699 AmigoDash[57994:1195566] (
        {
        "_id" =         {
            "$id" = 5579fde2e4b0588ab009f841;
        };
        hours = "10-11";
        image = imageURL;
        name = "Boleskine Bistro";
    },
        {
        "_id" =         {
            "$id" = 5579fe1fe4b0588ab009f84a;
        };
        hours = "9-11";
        image = imageURL;
        name = Amrikos;
    }
)
```

The problem I'm facing now is trying to iterate through the dictionary. When I try to do it, the code crashes. I'm new to working with JSON and iOS in general. Kind of overwhelmed. I ultimately need to get the name and image information from each unique object in the dictionary, so I have to iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: Show the code and the crash trace and message

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.

Answer (score 1):

From your log,your json is an array

I think using keyPath,it is easy

```
NSArray * array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&someError];
NSArray * namesArray = [array valueForKeyPath:@"name"]; //This will get a names array
NSArray * urlArray = [array valueForKeyPath:@"image"]; //This will get a url Array
```

If you still want to loop

```
NSArray * array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&someError];
for (NSDictionary * dic in array) {
    NSString * name = [dic valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString * hours = [dic valueForKey:@"hours"];
    //So on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the basics of JSON components and how the are parsed into iOS. I will give you a simple example I got [here](http://jsoneditoronline.org/). This I generally used for parsing JSON

```
{[
  {
    "array": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ],
    "boolean": true,
    "null": null,
    "number": 123,
    "object": {
      "a": "b",
          "c": "d",
      "e": "f"
    },
    "string": "Hello World"
  },
  {
    "array": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ],
    "boolean": true,
    "null": null,
    "number": 123,
    "object": {
      "a": "b",
      "c": "d",
      "e": "f"
    },
    "string": "Hello World"
  }
]}
```

This is the general kind of JSON you will get.

These are parsed as follows

1. `[]` denote an `array` which is parsed into a `NSArray`
2. `{}` denote an `dictionary` which is parsed into a `NSDictionary`
3. `true` or `false` is a `BOOL`
4. 123, 32, etc is `int`, `NSInteger`, `NSNumber`, etc
5. The text with `""` is for `NSString`

Now you should first pay attention to the structure, like what is inside what. And Then parse accordingly.

Let say for Above Example. The outermost object is an `NSDictionary` (`{}`).

```
 NSDictionary *cityJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:**Above JSON Data**];
```

Inside we have an `NSArray`(`[]`)

```
NSArray *testFeeds = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: cityData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Each of `testFeeds` object is an `NSDictionary`. This we we proceed from outermost to innermost object.

Comment: let me know what you have not understood and I might be able to explain more

Comment: Added some more Explanation.